# iOS project wants me to Upgrade assembler codgen and debugger

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated to xCode 4.3.2. When building the debugger wants me to upgrade to:
Build Settings

Target 'myApp' - Upgrade ARMV6 assembler codegen from THUMB to ARM mode
ARMV6 assembler codegen is set to THUMB. THis will upgrade the codgen setting for ARMV6 to the recommended value: ARM.

AND

Scheme 'myApp' - Upgrade debugger from GDB to LLDB
The debugger is set to GDB for the Run action. This will upgrade the debugger setting to the recommended value: LLDB.

Is it okay for me to do this? My app targets iOS 3.1 and above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LLDB has its advantages but IMHO is not as stable as GDB is. In most cases LLDB is fine and will work properly. When something weird happens while debugging, simply switch back to GDB within the Scheme settings. So accepting this Upgrade is just fine.

Creating ARM instead of THUMB code on ARMV6 basically is a workaround for a bad bug in LLVM (the objective-c compiler Apple now prefers). If you would not accept this change, chances are pretty high that ARMV6 targeted code will be falsely optimized, rendering issues into your App you would not have expected. To spell it out clear, the ARMV6 Thumb optimizing is buggy in LLVM 3.1 (as bundled with Xcode 4.3.2 and lower). So accepting this Upgrade is IMHO mandatory.